# Is there a way to prevent creation of app.config when adding a web reference?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, web-services, app-config

I have this Windows Form application that is a single application.

I recently created a ASP .NET Web Service on a server and added a Service Reference to this Web Service in my app.

It looks like it is forcing me to use an app.config now.

Is there a way to somehow prevent the creation of this file and have those settings embedded within the app.

I did some web searches on google and on stack overflow but wasn't able to come up with anything useful.

Thanks!

Comment: Embedding a config within the executable goes against the whole point of it being a config in the first place

Comment: possible duplicate of [Consume a SOAP web service without relying on the app.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703844/consume-a-soap-web-service-without-relying-on-the-app-config)