# Web service references without using an app.config

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, app-config, service-reference

Is it possible to add a service reference without utilizing the `app.config` to supply the bindings? In our application we have always just a new wsdl by using the .Net 2.0 Web Reference. Which requires no `app.config`.

Since the project is a DLL, it builds nicely without any worries of making sure the application running it, will supply the correct bindings through its `app.config`.

I hope that makes sense, from what I've seen/tried. There's no way to add a service reference without an `app.config` file.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. See the answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703844/consume-a-soap-web-service-without-relying-on-the-app-config#

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WSDL tool to create a class file which you can use to make requests. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6.aspx

I'm not sure if they still ship the tool with VS2010, but you should be able to find it quite easily.