# Create the instance of web service reference with passed binding and endpoint arguments

Tags: c#, web-services

I have added a web reference to a web service. The below configuration has been auto generated in app.config. I found out from the answer to the following question https://stackoverflow.com/a/3704312

that

> Usually, when you use the parameterless constructor (i.e. new
>   MyServicesSoapClient()), the settings in the app.config file will be
>   used. However, you can **bypass** the app.config file by explicitly
>   setting **the binding and endpoint** values in code and passing those
>   instances into the constructor.

Unfortunately, when I try to do it I keep getting '...does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments' error. 
**My question is why my instance of web service doesn't contain constructor with 2 arguments? Is this something to do with wsdl? How do I fix that?** 
I need to have default auto-generated binding and endpoint, but I also need a way of using other bindings (ex. https) and endpoints.

```
<system.serviceModel>
 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
   <binding name="MyServicesSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
     receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
     bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
     maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
     messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
     useDefaultWebProxy="true">
     <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
       maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
     <security mode="None">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
        realm="" />
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
     </security>
    </binding>
   </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
 <client>
  <endpoint address="http://services.mycompany.com/WebServices/MyServices.asmx"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyServicesSoap"
    contract="MyServices.MyServicesSoap" name="MyServicesSoap" />
 </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: What binding do you have your service ,  is it BasicHTTPonly??

Comment: I have defined other bindings as well, ex. Https. As default the service is using basicHttpBinding.

Comment: if you have the contract definition just use it in your project with Channel factory and you can use all endpoints you have added to your server in code

Comment: An solution is to add your tcp, https endpoint to your web.config, when you call your service calculator just specify your endpoint name